# Code For Binary Heapsort

Tags: java, binary, heap, pseudocode

I am practicing writing codes from pseudocodes. I found this while going over my Introductions to Algorithms text. I am sure I coded precisely to the pseudocode, however; it is not outputing what I want. The code is a `Binary Heapsort`. Instead of sorting my `input`, the code returns my `input` unchanged as an `output`. My thoughts towards the problem exist in the `build` method, where I casted `Math.floor()` to an `int`. This is my first time using `floor()`, so I believe my lack of understanding is the problem. I believe that I am returning the lowest approximated value of `heapsize/2` so I could branch my `Binary Heap`. But is this the case in my coding?

```
public class tester
{
public static void heapsort(int[] a)
{

    build(a);

    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        swap(a, 0, i);
        int heapsize = a.length - 1;
        heapify(a,0);
    }
}

public static void build(int[] a)
{
    int heapsize = a.length;
    int fl = (int) Math.floor((heapsize)/2);
    for (int i = fl; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        heapify(a, i);
    }
}

public static void heapify(int[] a, int root)
{
    int left = 2 * root + 1;
    int right = 2 * root + 2;
    int heapsize = a.length;
    int largest;

    if ( (left < heapsize) && (a[left] > a[root]))
    {
        largest = left;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = root;
    }
    if ( (right < heapsize) && (a[right] > a[largest]))
    {
        largest = right;
    }
    if (largest != root)
    {
        swap(a, a[root], a[largest]);
        heapify(a, largest);
    }

}

public static void swap(int[] a, int x, int y)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = new int[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    heapsort(a);
    for (int i : a)
    {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a little less code formatting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't used StackOverFlow until recently when I picked up coding. I saw others post full outlines of their code so I thought I could do the same.

Comment: I meant in the description of the code, using the `. Also I am rather new to stack over flow too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swap method doesn't work in Java, as you can only pass primitives by value, not by reference. You can modify the method like this:

```
public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

This would then be called like

```
    swap(a, 0, i);
```

instead of

```
    swap(a[0], a[i]);
```

And will correctly swap two numbers in the array.

Comment: Thank you for directing that to me, the output is still returning my input unchanged.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my mistake

Answer (score 0):

you should correct the heapify this way :

```
public static void heapify(int[] a, int root)
{

    int left = 2 * root + 1;
    int right = 2 * root + 2;
    int heapsize = a.length;
    int largest;

    if ( (left < heapsize) && (a[left] > a[root]))
    {
        largest = left;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = root;
    }
    if ( (right < heapsize) && (a[right] > a[largest]))
    {
        largest = right;
    }
    if (largest != root)
    {
        swap(a, root, largest);
        heapify(a, largest);
    }

}
```

so your total code will be :

```
public class tester
{
public static void heapsort(int[] a)
{

    build(a);

    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        swap(a, 0, i);
        int heapsize = a.length - 1;
        heapify(a,0);
    }
}

public static void build(int[] a)
{
    int heapsize = a.length;
    int fl = (int) Math.floor((heapsize)/2);
    for (int i = fl; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        heapify(a, i);
    }
}

public static void heapify(int[] a, int root)
{

    int left = 2 * root + 1;
    int right = 2 * root + 2;
    int heapsize = a.length;
    int largest;

    if ( (left < heapsize) && (a[left] > a[root]))
    {
        largest = left;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = root;
    }
    if ( (right < heapsize) && (a[right] > a[largest]))
    {
        largest = right;
    }
    if (largest != root)
    {
        swap(a, root, largest);
        heapify(a, largest);
    }

}

public static void swap(int[] a, int x, int y)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = new int[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    heapsort(a);
    for (int i : a)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I've already done the fix with the swap() in heapify(). I think my problem is in the heapsort method. I am returning my unsorted input.

Comment: First please try the code I've sent, I works for me! you can test it with sth like this: int[] a = {1,3,5,4,2,9};

Comment: OMG, I've just found an exception, you're right the code doesn't work right, and probably the logic of your code is wrong.